# Can I extend object dynamically by using a dynamic key and object as a value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

Let's say I have this function:

```js
var obj = {};
extend('myKey', 'myVal', 'mySomething');

function extend(key, val, something){
  $.extend(obj, {
    key : {
      value: val, 
      something: something
  }); // key is set as "key" and not as the key real value
  // I want obj to now have a key which is 'myKey'
  // and a value which is an object:
  // {value:'myVal', something:'mySomething'}
}
```

Could this be accomplished somehow?
I would like to do it without creating a new object in the extend function.

Comment: Are you just trying to add properties to your `obj`?

Comment: @KevinBoucher I think so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var obj = {};
extend('myKey', 'myVal', 'mySomething');

function extend(key, val, something){
        obj[key] = {value:val, something:something}; 
                                                
}

//this line is just to show the result of the function, not part of the solution.      
document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Just use plain JavaScript for this. You can assign a key to an object using the bracket notation. This way you can set it to a variable you defined.

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think of that! :)
Thanks m8.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just trying to add properties to `obj`, you can do this:

```
function addProp(obj, key, value) {
    obj[key] = value;
}
```